# Why do links from custom link / image fields not appear in the link database?

Tags: link-database, broken-links

I am using the following custom fields on our instance of Sitecore 9.0.2:

**Advance Image Field**

https://github.com/saadahmedkhan/sitecore-fields

**Sitecore Field Suite**

https://github.com/Velir/SitecoreFieldSuite

When doing some testing, I found that custom link type fields were not showing relationships between items. For example, if an Advance Image Field linked to a media library item, we were able to delete that media library item without any warnings about broken links.

How do we ensure these fields correctly register links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the custom field must patch `/App_Config/FieldTypes.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <fieldTypes>
          <!-- Register field so that image references will appear in the link database -->
          <fieldType name="Advance Image" type="SitecoreFramework.Fields.Fields.AdvanceImageField,SitecoreFramework.Fields" />
        </fieldTypes>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Once we confirmed showconfig.aspx was picking up this patch, I rebuilt the link database and the links were added to the database.

**EDIT:**

Another requirement is that the field must inherit from base Sitecore fields. In the case of FieldSuite, as of this date the module is not built in this manner.